# C# Selenium Chromedriver - Close Browser if Timeout reached

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

in my application I receive an *OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException* that blocks the application.

How can I close the browser that has timed out without blocking the application?

```
driveriso.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://*******");

IWebElement userTextBox = driveriso.FindElement(By.Id("login-username"));
userTextBox.Clear();
userTextBox.SendKeys(user);
IWebElement passTextBox = driveriso.FindElement(By.Id("login-password"));
passTextBox.Clear();
passTextBox.SendKeys(pass);
IWebElement logButton = driveriso.FindElement(By.Id("login-button"));
logButton.Click();
```

Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and post the actual exception message and indicate on which line of code the exception is thrown.

Comment: Had a similar issue recently, I just catch the exception and forcefully close the chromedriver.exe process if this happens. Probably doesn't fix the root cause though.